# Divide hline when double lines for columns appear, so to make separated columns

Tags: tables, rules

I want to create a table where for each cell, its lines do not cross the lines of other cells.

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|c|}}\hline
  First column & Second column \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With this, I get this:

[image]

while what I want is this:

[image]

Comment: `\cline{1-1}\cline{2-2}` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work (it is the same as `\hrule`)

Comment: A "fake" column `\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\hspace*{-10pt}}c|c|}
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
  First column & & Second column \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
  First column & & Second column \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}`

Comment: Thanks. In fact I am using something similar to that, but I want to know if there is any more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with `hhline`` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|c|}}
\hhline{-||-}
  First column & Second column \tabularnewline
\hhline{-||-}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, this is the package; I couldn't remember the name.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Mmmm... what about the second row? If I use hhline{=||=}, then the vertical lines do not break, if I use hline{=tb=} then the horizontal lines do not break. (hhline package documentation is quite cryptic)

Comment: Found it!: `\hhline{=::=}`  :-)

Comment: Exactly. But look at my updated answer: you also have to add a `|` or a `:` at the ends of the \hhlines.

Answer (score 2):

Two options: the first one using a fake column; the second one, using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\hspace*{-10pt}}c|c|}
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
  First column & & Second column \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
  First column & & Second column \tabularnewline
  \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}\par\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes=draw,column sep=2pt,row sep=-\pgflinewidth]
{
  First column & Second column \\
  First column & Second column \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]